# How to get Blender bge module as bge.py?

Tags: python, game-engine, blender

I tried to find the location of bge module of blender but after 2 days of research I got that it is the part of blender executable. 
Actually I want to use it in PyCharm for only code completion.
So i adopted another strategy, I used this code to get the methods or classes of a module `for i in dir(bge): print(i)` . But it was not what i was expecting, I have to apply this for each class and method and it returns only names and I have to write them in the form of functions or classes. Is there any possibility to achieve this? There are some repositories on github for this but they dont have bge. Any suggestion or help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no way.

It is possible to build blender as a bpy module, allowing it to be imported outside of the blender executable. This is possible as part of the build system which does not currently implement the same for the bge module.

As blender is open source, you are free to alter the build system to also make building the bge module an option.